# Custom (OData) routes in Restangular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, restangular

On the server side, I'm using Web API with the OData routing convention, which means that my route for getting a single entity looks something like this:

```
/api/v1/Products(1)
```

rather than:

```
/api/v1/Products/1
```

Normally, in Restangular, I'd be able to get a single entity with something like this:

```
Restangular.one('Product', 1);
```

But that doesn't work for my OData endpoint.  I've looked at `customGET`, and `setRequestInterceptor` but I can't seem to find an example of or figure out how to change the route to match my endpoint.  Preferably globally since all of my entities will have this same format.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Restangular documentation details how to create a custom configuration, you could do the same by editing the source restangular.js but this extensibility point allows us to keep a clean implementation that should be compatible with most customisations or future versions of RestAngular as well as allowing side-by-side standard REST APIs and OData v4 APIs.

[How to create a Restangular service with a different configuration from the global one](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-to-create-a-restangular-service-with-a-different-configuration-from-the-global-one)

```
// Global configuration
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:16486');
  RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({ id: 'Id' });
});

// Restangular service targeting OData v4 on a the specified route
app.factory('ODataRestangular', function(Restangular) {
  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl(RestangularConfigurer.baseUrl + '/odata');

    // OData v4 controller(key) Item Route convention
    RestangularConfigurer.urlCreatorFactory.path.prototype.base = function(current) {
      var __this = this;
      return _.reduce(this.parentsArray(current), function(acum, elem) {
        var elemUrl;
        var elemSelfLink = RestangularConfigurer.getUrlFromElem(elem);
        if (elemSelfLink) {
          if (RestangularConfigurer.isAbsoluteUrl(elemSelfLink)) {
            return elemSelfLink;
          } else {
            elemUrl = elemSelfLink;
          }
        } else {
          elemUrl = elem[RestangularConfigurer.restangularFields.route];

          if (elem[RestangularConfigurer.restangularFields.restangularCollection]) {
            var ids = elem[RestangularConfigurer.restangularFields.ids];
            if (ids) {
              // Crude Implementation of 'several', don't try this with more than
              // 60 Ids, performance degrades exponentially for large lists of ids.
              elemUrl += '?$filter=((Id eq ' + ids.join(')or(Id eq ') + '))';
            }
          } else {
            var elemId;
            if (RestangularConfigurer.useCannonicalId) {
              elemId = RestangularConfigurer.getCannonicalIdFromElem(elem);
            } else {
              elemId = RestangularConfigurer.getIdFromElem(elem);
            }

            if (RestangularConfigurer.isValidId(elemId) && !elem.singleOne) {
              elemUrl += '(' + (RestangularConfigurer.encodeIds ? encodeURIComponent(elemId) : elemId) + ')';
            }
          }
        }
        acum = acum.replace(/\/$/, '') + '/' + elemUrl;
        return __this.normalizeUrl(acum);

      }, RestangularConfigurer.baseUrl);
    };

    // add a response interceptor for OData v4:
    RestangularConfigurer.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
      var extractedData;
      // Collection requests are 'getList' operations
      if (operation === "getList") {
        // return the value array
        extractedData = data.value;
      } else {
        // return the first item in the array
        if(data.value.length > 0)
          extractedData = data.value[0];
      }
      // pass the metadata back
      if(extractedData) {
        extractedData.meta = { context: data['@odata.context'] };
        if(data['@odata.count'])
          extractedData.meta.count = data['@odata.count'];
      }
      return extractedData;
    });
  });
});
```

Implementation example:

```
// Controller for list route
function ListCtrl($scope, ODataRestangular) {
  $scope.providers = ODataRestangular.all("providers").getList({ $count:true }).$object;
  $scope.some = ODataRestangular.several("providers", 15,16,17,18).getList();
  $scope.single = ODataRestangular.one("providers", 15).get();
}
```

Captured URLs from network Traffic:

`http://localhost:16486/odata/providers?$count=true`

`http://localhost:16486/odata/providers?$filter=((Id eq 15)or(Id eq 16)or(Id eq 17)or(Id eq 18))`

`http://localhost:16486/odata/providers(15)`

> I struggled to try to write a custom service factory and to modify BreezeJS to work with OData v4 and only recently stumbled into Restangular, I can now really appreciate the extensible design that went into restangular, the general lack of documented client side framework support has been the Achilles heel that has prevented a wider adoption of OData v4. I hope this answer contributes to getting more developers onboard with version 4.

Answer (score 0):

Restangular does not explicitly support OData APIs. You can make the basics work, but you would probably be better off using a library that does support querying an OData API, like [breeze.js](http://www.breezejs.com/).